# R how to fill in missing dates based on other measurements within a database

Tags: r, date, missing-data

Here I have a database that is a summary of a larger database where I censused reef fishes for all experimental units (Module #) at either Waikiki or Hanauma Bay.  For any given sample period (TimeStep) all modules at a given Site were censused on the same date.  I used complete() to fill in missing values where census data were missing (eg. no fish were observed during a module census).  I am attempting to fill dates for my database based on Site (Site_long) and TimeStep.

#### Data Header

[image]

#### Database

```
data <- structure(list(Date = structure(c(18244, 18244, 17503, 17503, 
17503, 17503, 17873, 17873, 18309, 18309, 18314, 17977, 17977, 
17977, 17671, 17671, 17671, 17671, 17311, 17311, 17311, 18411, 
18411, 18050, 17775, 17775, 17775, 18154, 18154, 18154, 17416, 
17416, 17416, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA), class = "Date"), Year = c(2019, 2019, 2017, 2017, 
2017, 2017, 2018, 2018, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2018, 
2018, 2018, 2018, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2020, 2020, 2019, 2018, 2018, 
2018, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 
2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 
2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 
2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 
2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 
2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 
2017, 2017, 2017, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 
2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 
2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 
2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 
2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 
2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 
2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 
2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 
2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 
2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 
2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 
2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2020, 2020, 2020, 
2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 
2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 
2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 
2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 
2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 
2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020), `Module #` = c(111, 
113, 111, 113, 115, 116, 115, 116, 111, 113, 115, 112, 114, 115, 
113, 114, 115, 116, 111, 113, 115, 112, 115, 115, 112, 113, 115, 
111, 113, 116, 111, 113, 115, 111, 111, 111, 111, 111, 111, 111, 
111, 111, 112, 112, 112, 112, 112, 112, 112, 112, 112, 112, 112, 
112, 113, 113, 113, 113, 113, 113, 113, 113, 113, 114, 114, 114, 
114, 114, 114, 114, 114, 114, 114, 114, 114, 115, 115, 115, 115, 
115, 115, 115, 115, 115, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 
116, 116, 116, 111, 111, 111, 111, 111, 111, 111, 111, 111, 111, 
111, 111, 112, 112, 112, 112, 112, 112, 112, 112, 112, 112, 112, 
113, 113, 113, 113, 113, 113, 113, 113, 113, 113, 114, 114, 114, 
114, 114, 114, 114, 114, 114, 114, 114, 115, 115, 115, 115, 115, 
115, 115, 115, 115, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 
116, 111, 111, 111, 111, 111, 111, 111, 111, 111, 111, 112, 112, 
112, 112, 112, 112, 112, 112, 112, 112, 112, 113, 113, 113, 113, 
113, 113, 113, 113, 113, 113, 114, 114, 114, 114, 114, 114, 114, 
114, 114, 114, 114, 115, 115, 115, 115, 115, 115, 115, 115, 115, 
115, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 111, 
111, 111, 111, 111, 111, 111, 111, 111, 111, 111, 112, 112, 112, 
112, 112, 112, 112, 112, 112, 112, 112, 113, 113, 113, 113, 113, 
113, 113, 113, 113, 113, 113, 114, 114, 114, 114, 114, 114, 114, 
114, 114, 114, 114, 114, 115, 115, 115, 115, 115, 115, 115, 115, 
115, 115, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 
116), Site_long = c("Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", 
"Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", 
"Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", 
"Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", 
"Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", 
"Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", 
"Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", 
"Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", 
"Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", 
"Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", 
"Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", 
"Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", 
"Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", 
"Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", 
"Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", 
"Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", 
"Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", 
"Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", 
"Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", 
"Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", 
"Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", 
"Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", 
"Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", 
"Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", 
"Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", 
"Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", 
"Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", 
"Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", 
"Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", 
"Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", 
"Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", 
"Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", 
"Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", 
"Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", 
"Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", 
"Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", 
"Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", 
"Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", 
"Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", 
"Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", 
"Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", 
"Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", 
"Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", 
"Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", 
"Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", 
"Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", 
"Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", 
"Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", 
"Waikiki", "Waikiki"), Shelter = c("High", "High", "High", "High", 
"High", "Low", "High", "Low", "High", "High", "High", "Low", 
"Low", "High", "High", "Low", "High", "Low", "High", "High", 
"High", "Low", "High", "High", "Low", "High", "High", "High", 
"High", "Low", "High", "High", "High", "High", "High", "High", 
"High", "High", "High", "High", "High", "High", "Low", "Low", 
"Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", 
"Low", "High", "High", "High", "High", "High", "High", "High", 
"High", "High", "Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", 
"Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", "High", "High", "High", "High", 
"High", "High", "High", "High", "High", "Low", "Low", "Low", 
"Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", "High", 
"High", "High", "High", "High", "High", "High", "High", "High", 
"High", "High", "High", "Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", 
"Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", "High", "High", "High", "High", 
"High", "High", "High", "High", "High", "High", "Low", "Low", 
"Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", 
"High", "High", "High", "High", "High", "High", "High", "High", 
"High", "Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", 
"Low", "Low", "High", "High", "High", "High", "High", "High", 
"High", "High", "High", "High", "Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", 
"Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", "High", "High", "High", 
"High", "High", "High", "High", "High", "High", "High", "Low", 
"Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", 
"Low", "High", "High", "High", "High", "High", "High", "High", 
"High", "High", "High", "Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", 
"Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", "High", "High", "High", "High", 
"High", "High", "High", "High", "High", "High", "High", "Low", 
"Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", 
"Low", "High", "High", "High", "High", "High", "High", "High", 
"High", "High", "High", "High", "Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", 
"Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", "High", "High", 
"High", "High", "High", "High", "High", "High", "High", "High", 
"Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", 
"Low", "Low", "Low"), TimeStep = c("11", "11", "3", "3", "3", 
"3", "7", "7", "12", "12", "12", "8", "8", "8", "5", "5", "5", 
"5", "1", "1", "1", "13", "13", "9", "6", "6", "6", "10", "10", 
"10", "2", "2", "2", "10", "11", "12", "13", "5", "6", "7", "8", 
"9", "1", "10", "11", "12", "13", "2", "3", "5", "6", "7", "8", 
"9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "1", "10", 
"11", "12", "13", "2", "3", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", 
"12", "13", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "1", "10", "11", "12", "13", 
"2", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "1", "10", "11", "12", "13", "2", 
"3", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "1", "10", "11", "12", "13", "2", 
"3", "5", "7", "8", "9", "1", "10", "11", "12", "13", "2", "3", 
"7", "8", "9", "1", "10", "11", "12", "13", "2", "3", "6", "7", 
"8", "9", "1", "10", "11", "12", "13", "2", "3", "8", "9", "1", 
"10", "11", "12", "13", "2", "3", "6", "8", "9", "1", "12", "13", 
"2", "3", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "1", "10", "11", "12", "13", 
"2", "3", "5", "6", "7", "9", "1", "12", "13", "2", "3", "5", 
"6", "7", "8", "9", "1", "10", "11", "12", "13", "2", "3", "5", 
"6", "7", "9", "1", "10", "11", "12", "13", "2", "3", "5", "6", 
"7", "1", "11", "12", "13", "2", "3", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", 
"1", "10", "11", "13", "2", "3", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "1", 
"10", "11", "12", "2", "3", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "1", "10", 
"11", "13", "2", "3", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "1", "10", "11", 
"12", "13", "2", "3", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "1", "10", "11", 
"2", "3", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "1", "10", "11", "12", "13", 
"2", "3", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"), total_biomass = c(0.0347972963845844, 
0.0491864247516633, 0.0337429360353172, 0.0491864247516633, 0.0676700712806197, 
0.0176129136061979, 0.0463414029816723, 0.0438269494805073, 0.0540876987656689, 
0.0540876987656689, 0.013587464291258, 0.00803709822823084, 0.00467403151010407, 
0.0409256138571204, 0.0620895115023818, 0.0209695276260751, 0.0204081680175056, 
0.00206199419933497, 0.01080234898264, 0.0316349973376856, 0.00612831747253596, 
0.0025587897405708, 0.00969619960291588, 0.124762345913799, 0.00202327772014947, 
0.00403651893214743, 0.0316209605244676, 0.016930666455176, 0.0219387977347698, 
0.00121768478272671, 0.0361091366626131, 0.0122566349450719, 
0.00969619960291588, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Season = c("winter", "winter", 
"winter", "winter", "winter", "winter", "winter", "winter", "spring", 
"spring", "spring", "spring", "spring", "spring", "summer", "summer", 
"summer", "summer", "summer", "summer", "summer", "summer", "summer", 
"summer", "fall", "fall", "fall", "fall", "fall", "fall", "fall", 
"fall", "fall", "fall", "winter", "spring", "summer", "summer", 
"fall", "winter", "spring", "summer", "summer", "fall", "winter", 
"spring", "summer", "fall", "winter", "summer", "fall", "winter", 
"spring", "summer", "fall", "winter", "spring", "summer", "summer", 
"fall", "winter", "spring", "summer", "summer", "fall", "winter", 
"spring", "summer", "fall", "winter", "summer", "fall", "winter", 
"spring", "summer", "fall", "winter", "spring", "summer", "summer", 
"fall", "winter", "spring", "summer", "summer", "fall", "winter", 
"spring", "summer", "fall", "summer", "fall", "winter", "spring", 
"summer", "summer", "fall", "winter", "spring", "summer", "fall", 
"winter", "summer", "fall", "winter", "spring", "summer", "summer", 
"fall", "winter", "spring", "summer", "fall", "winter", "summer", 
"winter", "spring", "summer", "summer", "fall", "winter", "spring", 
"summer", "fall", "winter", "winter", "spring", "summer", "summer", 
"fall", "winter", "spring", "summer", "fall", "winter", "fall", 
"winter", "spring", "summer", "summer", "fall", "winter", "spring", 
"summer", "fall", "winter", "spring", "summer", "summer", "fall", 
"winter", "spring", "summer", "fall", "winter", "fall", "spring", 
"summer", "summer", "spring", "summer", "fall", "winter", "summer", 
"fall", "winter", "spring", "summer", "summer", "fall", "winter", 
"spring", "summer", "fall", "winter", "summer", "fall", "winter", 
"summer", "summer", "spring", "summer", "fall", "winter", "summer", 
"fall", "winter", "spring", "summer", "summer", "fall", "winter", 
"spring", "summer", "fall", "winter", "summer", "fall", "winter", 
"summer", "summer", "fall", "winter", "spring", "summer", "fall", 
"winter", "summer", "fall", "winter", "summer", "winter", "spring", 
"summer", "fall", "winter", "summer", "fall", "winter", "spring", 
"summer", "summer", "fall", "winter", "summer", "fall", "winter", 
"summer", "fall", "winter", "spring", "summer", "summer", "fall", 
"winter", "spring", "fall", "winter", "summer", "fall", "winter", 
"spring", "summer", "summer", "fall", "winter", "summer", "fall", 
"winter", "summer", "fall", "winter", "spring", "summer", "summer", 
"fall", "winter", "spring", "summer", "fall", "winter", "summer", 
"fall", "winter", "spring", "summer", "summer", "fall", "winter", 
"fall", "winter", "summer", "fall", "winter", "spring", "summer", 
"summer", "fall", "winter", "spring", "summer", "fall", "winter", 
"summer", "fall", "winter", "spring", "summer")), row.names = c(NA, 
-288L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

In order to fill dates based on other entries from the same Site and TimeStep, I tried using the complete() function.

#### Attempted Code

```
data <- data %>% 
  complete(Date, nesting(Site_long, TimeStep))
```

The desired output should have rows that all contain a Date.  The Date should be filled such that if it was missing, the new Date value should correspond to the Date that observations were made for that given Site and TimeStep.

For example, in the header data, you can see that the first row with a missing Date is for Module # 111 at Waikiki during TimeStep 10.  The date should be filled such that it matches the Date entered for any Module # at Waikiki during TimeStep 10 (2019-09-15).  Thanks in advance for your input!

Answer (score 1):

You can merge those rows with non-missing `Date` into the original data by `Module #`, `Site_long`, and `TimeStep`.

```
library(dplyr)

data %>%
  filter(!is.na(Date)) %>%
  select(Date, Site_long, TimeStep) %>%
  distinct(Site_long, TimeStep, .keep_all = TRUE) %>% 
  left_join(data, ., by = c("Site_long", "TimeStep")) %>%
  mutate(Date = coalesce(Date.x, Date.y), .keep = "unused", .before = Year)
```

Comment: Darren Tsai Your code gives the following error: "Error in select(., Date, `Module #`, Site_long, TimeStep) : 
  unused arguments (Date, `Module #`, Site_long, TimeStep)".  I do not understand at all why or how this is happening

Comment: Also I broke apart the code into 3 separate lines in case that was the issue and even though it runs without errors, I get a database that still has 0 biomass entries with no corresponding date ```[r] data_dates <- data %>% 
  filter(!is.na(Date))

data <- left_join(data, data_dates, by = c("Module #", "Site_long", "TimeStep"))

data <- data %>% mutate(Date = coalesce(Date.x, Date.y), .keep = "unused", .before = Year.x) ```

Comment: @EricDilley I use the data you provided in your post and get a great output with my code! Maybe it's owed to the package version of `dplyr`. How about updating your `dplyr` and trying again!

Comment: I tried only loading the tidyverse and then I didn't get an error.  However some of the dates are not filled in and still have NA for Date.   I have put my resulting database with your code in the question.  Does your result have the entire date column filled in?

Comment: I wasn't able to post the database because it exceeds the character limit.  But as I said, the Date column still has NA entries.

Comment: @EricDilley Fixed! But there is still a problem. For `Site_long = Waikiki` & `TimeStep = 12`, there are two dates matched, i.e. `2020-02-17` and `2020-02-22`. If there is a row with missing date and `Site_long = Waikiki` & `TimeStep = 12`, which date should it match?

Comment: That makes more sense.  So in general, if multiple dates are present for a Site x TimeStep combination, I would like the date for missing date rows to become the most recent date with observations.  So in this case you cited, I would want the date "2020-02-22" to be used to fill for empty dates.